# Not understanding the answer to the inverse of a function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

$$f(x)\quad =1+\sqrt { 1+x } $$

$$y\quad =1+\sqrt { 1+x } $$

$$y^{ 2 }\quad =1+1+x$$

$$y^{ 2 }-2\quad =x$$

How is it $x=y^{ 2 }-2y$ ?

Comment: Let $\sqrt {1+x}=z$ then $y=1+z$ does not imply $y^2=1+z^2$ but $y^2=(1+z)^2=1+2z+z^2$. Another approach would use $(y-1)^2=z^2$.

Comment: $y^2=1+2\sqrt{1+x}+1+x$.

Comment: I think you want $x=y^2-2y$ at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have said $$y = 1 + \sqrt {1 + x} $$ so that $$x = {\left( {y - 1} \right)^2} - 1$$by interchanging $x$ and $y$, we get $$y = {\left( {x - 1} \right)^2} - 1 = {x^2} - 2x$$ which is the inverse of the initial function. We could check the answer by noting that if $g$ is the inverse of $f$, then $gof$ should be the unity operator. Now $f(x) = 1 + \sqrt {1 + x} $ and $g(x) = {x^2} - 2x$ so that $$\displaylines{
  g(f(x)) = f{(x)^2} - 2f(x) \cr 
   = {\left( {1 + \sqrt {1 + x} } \right)^2} - 2\left( {1 + \sqrt {1 + x} } \right) \cr 
   = 1 + 2\sqrt {1 + x}  + 1 + x - 2 - 2\sqrt {1 + x}  \cr 
   = x \cr} $$which confirms our answer.

Answer (score 0):

$$y\quad =1+\sqrt { 1+x }\iff y-1 = \sqrt{1+x}$$ 
$$ \iff (y-1)^2 = 1+x $$
$$\iff y^2 -2y + 1 = 1 + x $$
$$\iff y^2 - 2y = x$$

Your error is introduced when you attempted to square the right-hand side: $$(1 +\sqrt{x+1})^2 = 1 + 2\sqrt{x+1} + x+1 \neq 2 + x$$

This is just a straight-forward use of the fact that $$(a + b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2 \neq a^2 + b^2$$